# Implementing Circle constructor in JavaScript, without ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Eric Faust typed up a Circle constructor function in the following article about ES6 classes: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/07/es6-in-depth-classes/

I was wondering:

1. Why does he use `defineProperty`? Can't we just implement the behavior straight  into the constructor. For example: `Circle.draw = function draw() {..}`
2. Why use `get` / `set` instead of just having the state in normal properties: `Circle.circleCount`?
3. Which properties should be implemented directly on new instance objects, via `this` in constructor, vs on `Constructor.prototype` (given how both make the properties available to new instances)?

Eric's code:

```js
function Circle(radius) {
  this.radius = radius;
  Circle.circlesMade++;
}

Circle.draw = function draw(circle, canvas) { /* Canvas drawing code */ }

Object.defineProperty(Circle, "circlesMade", {
  get: function() {
    return !this._count ? 0 : this._count;
  },

  set: function(val) {
    this._count = val;
  }
});

Circle.prototype = {
  area: function area() {
    return Math.pow(this.radius, 2) * Math.PI;
  }
};

Object.defineProperty(Circle.prototype, "radius", {
  get: function() {
    return this._radius;
  },

  set: function(radius) {
    if (!Number.isInteger(radius))
      throw new Error("Circle radius must be an integer.");
    this._radius = radius;
  }
});

let c1 = new Circle(10);
console.log(c1.area());
console.log(Circle.circlesMade);
```

My version:

```js
function Circle(_radius) {
  this.radius = _radius;

  Circle.draw = function draw(circle, canvas) {
    /* Canvas drawing code */
  };

  !Circle.circleCount ?
    (Circle.circleCount = 1) //First construction
    :
    (Circle.circleCount = Circle.circleCount + 1);

  this.area = function area() {
    return Math.pow(this.radius, 2) * Math.PI;
  };
}

let c1 = new Circle(10);
console.log(Circle.circleCount);
console.log(c1.area());

let c2 = new Circle(20);
console.log(Circle.circleCount);
console.log(c2.area());
```

Comment: It seems like the example is totally made up to show the full atrocity of ES5, and how much simpler the same things would become with ES6 `class` syntax. Of course, in real ES5 one would have written this very differently (much simpler), but the exact equivalent of that (like primitive static properties) could not have been expressed in ES6.

Comment: `Circle.draw` is a *static* property and should definitely not be assigned inside the constructor. Same for `Circle.circleCount` - you should initialise it to `0` outside of the constructor, and increment it when creating an instance

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. As you point out, It was a clear mistake to declare properties that are own properties of the constructor function, inside the constructor function itself. We obviously don't want it to be redeclared each time a new object is created. For `circleCount` I have the check in there, to avoid multiple re-declarations, but I guess it is more optimal to do it outside, thus avoiding any check at all. To my understanding, the only improvements `class` adds on top of well-implemented ES5, is 1) the ability to put all related code under one single block, and 2) static property inheritance.

Comment: Yes, that and the `get`/`set` syntax from ES5 object literals for getters and setters (which needed `Object.defineProperty` before if you didn't want to replace but mutate the prototype object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer using the constructor's prototype object for functions that will be shared with instances rather than defining a new function on each instance. This can save memory because you only have one instance of the function rather than a new copy for each instance you create.

You can also define `circleCount` on the prototype since all instances need the same number. You just need to be a little careful changing it to make sure you don't create a shadowed property on each instance. Then each instance can directly provide the count via the prototype chain.

Doing that complicates the function, but simplifies the rest of you code:

```js
function Circle(_radius) {
  this.radius = _radius;
  // creating an instance increments the count for everyone
  Circle.prototype.circleCount++ // not this.circleCount++ which will create a new property on instance
}
Circle.prototype.draw = function draw(circle, canvas) {
  /* Canvas drawing code */
};
Circle.prototype.area = function() {
  return Math.pow(this.radius, 2) * Math.PI;
}
Circle.prototype.circleCount = 0


let c1 = new Circle(10);
console.log(c1.circleCount);
console.log(c1.area());

let c2 = new Circle(20);
console.log(c2.circleCount);
console.log(c2.area());
```

Also, regarding the question about `Object.defineProperty`. It looks like he's using that so he can set getter and setter functions rather than just returning the property. You could do that with `area` with something like:

```
Object.defineProperty(Circle.prototype, "area", {
    get: function() {
       return Math.pow(this.radius, 2) * Math.PI;
    }
});
```

Which would allow you to access area as if ti were a property on each instance:

```
c2.area // instead of a function c2.area()
```

You could set area as a property directly, but then if you change the radius you need to also change the area. I guess which is best depends on whether radius will ever change.

Comment: Thanks Mark, makes sense re the memory and swapping to prototype. Any idea on question 1. and 2.? He is trying to defend the creation of classes, but what he wrote can be simplified to your code.

Comment: The latest edit talks a bit about 1 and 2. I think a es6 class could be nice for this and would probably go that route. It would let you set up all the methods in the class declaration, which I think is very readable. You can also set up getters and setters right on the class to. But underneath it all, it still boils down to functions and prototypes.

Comment: Yep, but I guess what bothers me a bit is he uses all that convoluted code to justify classes, when in fact the getters / setters are not needed at all. Thus, neither is defineProperty. Which makes the only case for classes that we can add the prototype methods to within the constructor definition itself (I guess it does not get recreated for each instance then?). And that does not seem like a lot of benefit to me. He made his original code overly complex, so it looks like a big gain.

Comment: Sure, I think it's fair to say if you don't need the things classes make simpler, then you could just as easily use functions. If you **do** want getters/setters, easy inheritance, quick function declaration shortcuts, then classes are pretty nice.

Comment: 1) Wouldn't inheritance be as easy as setting the .prototype of the constructor? 2) Is the list you sent basically what it tries to improve?